# Linux zip tool that supports mutithreading

Tags: linux, compression

The only one I know is 7za but it shows speed similar to zip.

I made a quick test for zip, 7za (with -mmt8) and jar. Results are almost same, and 7za is lowest one (what is strange 'cos it should run in 8 threads)

Is there any multithread impleemntations?

P.S. I need only zip/gzip implementation. Unfortunatly I can't use other archivers.

Answer (score 4):

I made good experiences with [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/).

Comment: Thanks, will try it! Unfortunatly, this is my first question and I can't vote up your answer.